# how to install windows programs in ubuntu 14.0.1

Tags: 14.04

I have recently switched from windows to ubuntu 14.0.1.
Since I am a beginner, I have not much idea regarding ubuntu.
I want to install some programs that I use in windows. I have the set ups but I am unable to install them in ubuntu. Please help.

Comment: you can use `wine`. Install it using `sudo apt-get install wine`.

Comment: what programs are you trying to install

Comment: it says unable to locate package wine

Comment: like vlc media player

Comment: VLC is already available in Ubuntu. just press <Ctrl>+<Alt>+<T> to open terminal and then run `sudo apt-get install vlc`. for more details read [How do I install applications in Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/questions/307280/how-do-i-install-applications-in-ubuntu)

Comment: and how do I install wine. It says unable to locate package wine when i enter the apt get command you told

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Wine-on-Ubuntu

Comment: you can also try 'play on linux'

Comment: Now it is time to use Free/Opensource Applications for Ubuntu Linux (can be installed from software centecr or by `apt`) rather than using windows software!

Answer (score 1):

you could not install a windows programs directly. There are some softwares are available like Wine,Crossover Linux etc.. you can download it from Internet as .deb file and you could install it via terminal using the following command.

To install a downloaded .deb file:

```
sudo dpkg -i packagename.deb
```

To remove a installed package:

```
sudo dpkg -r packagename
```

Or directly you can install wine via terminal by following commands.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa

sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install wine1.6 winetricks
```

Comment: @VishalSharma go this site:http://en.uptodown.com/ubuntu

Comment: can u please provide me the link to download wine as .deb file

Comment: @VishalSharma http://wine.en.uptodown.com/ubuntu

Comment: Problem solved....thanx a lot